# O que fazer quando um usuário remove a pergunta sem aviso?

Tags: debate, perguntas, exclusão

[Essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/49040/215) foi feita há umas 2 horas atrás, e nesse meio tempo estive tentando ajudar o usuário com seu problema. Entretanto, sem aviso nem explicação, ele removeu a pergunta enquanto eu estava editando minha resposta à mesma (felizmente eu já havia postado a resposta, então não perdi todo o meu trabalho!). Só percebi que a mesma havia sido excluída depois de postar.

O que fazer numa situação dessas? É claro que o AP tem direito de remover suas próprias perguntas, pelo motivo que bem entender (se o sistema deixar, é claro - no caso, só havia a minha resposta, e ela não havia tido nenhum voto positivo[1]). Mas é bem frustrante quando você gasta tempo tentando responder uma pergunta só para vê-la sumir levando junto seu esforço.

Eu *poderia* recomendá-la para restauração, minha dúvida é: devo? Sim ou não, e por que?

[1]: muito embora o AP tenha comentado (e depois apagado o comentário) dizendo que a solução funcionava, embora não o atendesse 100% bem - o que inclusive me levou a dedicar *mais tempo* à pergunta numa tentativa de prover uma solução alternativa...

Comment: Sim, deve, inclusive para educar o usuário. Neste caso específico, já desfiz a exclusão. Não posso me estender nesse assunto no momento, mas creio que em geral deve-se mesmo votar por desfazer, e aguardar para ver se mais dois membros da comunidade concordam.

Comment: "É claro que o AP tem direito de remover suas próprias perguntas" – nem tanto, segundo [termos de uso do site](http://stackexchange.com/legal), que ainda carecem de tradução: *You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You.*

Comment: @bfavaretto É claro, sob os termos da CC BY-SA não só a SE mas qualquer um que ganhar acesso a esse conteúdo pode mantê-lo e utilizá-lo, quanto a essa "parte legal" não tem a menor dúvida. É mais uma questão de etiqueta mesmo: se o interesse coletivo puder ser conciliado com o interesse individual, tanto melhor. De todo modo, se o AP removeu sem comentar, não vejo mal em restaurar da mesma forma, se ele tiver problemas com isso cabe a ele se pronunciar a respeito...

Comment: Seria legal que alguém com conhecimento jurídico pudesse opinar, porque minha interpretação da CC BY-SA não foi a mesma da sua. Eu posso criar um conteúdo derivado citando a fonte, mas não poderia me apropriar de conteúdo alheio ou impedir sua exclusão. Se a licença garantisse isso, os termos de uso nem precisariam dizer o que eu citei. Essa é a minha interpretação, porém sou leigo no assunto.

Comment: O mgibsonbr tá certo quando diz que sempre que possível precisamos tentar alinhar o interesse coletivo com o individual. Tentamos fazer isso o máximo possível. Ao mesmo tempo, qualquer pergunta no site que seja editada, comentada, respondida ou votada passa a ser produto do trabalho de mais de 1 indivíduo, e considerada parte do corpo do **site** e não propriedade do autor. Permitir remoções arbitrárias é, também, permitir que alguém desaproprie o trabalho de dezenas de outras pessoas, potencialmente. É uma situação complicada.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Já me deparei algumas vezes com este fenômeno. Tentei avisar a moderação de uma forma ou de outra do ocorrido além de votar para reabrir. Até mesmo em casos que eu estava escrevendo mas ainda não tinha postado uma resposta.

Na minha visão enquanto o autor retém a autoria do que posta no *site*, ele perde a propriedade do que postou. A pergunta é da comunidade.

Acho que devemos restaurar a pergunta se ela parece ser interessante. Se o autor não quer mais ser associado com ela, acho que deve pedir para o moderador desvinculá-lo da pergunta. Eventualmente cabe uma edição para não criar problemas de privacidade do que foi postado. E a remoção deve ser aceita se é impossível remover dados que prejudicam a privacidade sem comprometer a pergunta.

Como sei que há casos de usuários que fazem isto com frequência, eles não entendem que a comunidade deve ajudar a todos e não só a ele, acho que é preciso avisar a moderação quando não é um caso isolado. Não sei qual é a política oficial mas acho que no mínimo é preciso entender o porquê deste comportamento e ver se ele pode ser mudado e ainda se alguma coisa pode/deve ser feita se o usuário se recusa a mudar.

A não ser que tenha disposições em contrário ou tenha um motivo plausível a remoção deve ser revertida a pedido de alguém interessado.

Em último caso caso isto não seja possível sempre é possível refazer a pergunta por conta própria e dar uma resposta. Já tive que fazer isto também.

Comment: É justamente nesse ponto de "ser interessante" que surgiu minha dúvida. Da mesma forma que temos uma regra de ["não migrar porcaria"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446), creio que se esforçar para que uma pergunta ruim tenha a remoção revertida com o único propósito de "preservar seu esforço" seria uma atitude indesejável do ponto de vista coletivo. Num caso desses, melhor viver com o prejuízo... Resta então saber o quão interessante uma pergunta deve ser para justificar a restauração, e isso toca na subjetividade (basta *eu* gostar dela e dar meu voto? Ou é preciso mais? etc).

Comment: Concordo também com a ideia de desvincular o autor da pergunta, se ele assim quiser. É sempre bom respeitar o desejo do autor, isso é algo que tem de ser conciliado com os interesses da comunidade. Tem de haver um meio-termo.

Comment: Concordo, aí vai do seu julgamento individual se vale a reversão ou não, porque só você vai iniciar a tentativa de reversão. Embora possível, é improvável que outra pessoa que não está envolvida inicie. Por outro lado, nós baixamos bastante a barra da qualidade aqui. Eu não sei mais definir facilmente o que é interessante ou não. Na dúvida eu acho que deve deixar no *site*. Não é o meu gosto mas é a postura que se adotou aqui. E vou respeitar isto. Eu já fiz o que podia para não acontecer, agora chegou a hora de eu aceitar.

Comment: É uma daquelas situações em que qualquer linha que se trace demarcando o que é "interessante" não passa de uma ilusão de ordem. Uma pergunta, por mais fraca que pareça, sempre é interessante para uma pessoa que se dispôs à respondê-la, por exemplo. E ninguém gosta de ver seu trabalho desaparecer, como foi o caso do @mgibsonbr agora. Qualquer tentativa de escrever uma regra aqui é vã... No final das contas, se alguém achar que a pergunta deve ser restaurada, que vote como tal e espere que a comunidade concorde.

Answer (score 2):

> Eu poderia recomendá-la para restauração, minha dúvida é: devo? Sim ou
>   não, e por que?

Sim deve, é a intenção do SO ser um fórum de troca de experiência e conhecimento, **as medalhas e reputação são apenas incentivos, não o objetivo fim**. A pergunta só deveria ser apagada em caso ser contra as regras, e o usuário educado de como o fórum funciona. Isso aqui não é um restaurante, a dúvida foi colocada e como somos instruídos a não discutir e sempre tentar agregar as respostas são colocadas e se não forem da satisfação do usuário não serão marcadas como resolvido, mas no futuro podem vir a ser de interesse de outros, muitas vezes (o que venho observando) as pessoas que perguntam nem sabem o que perguntam ou desejam soluções de "má prática".

> [1]: muito embora o AP tenha comentado (e depois apagado o comentário)
>   dizendo que a solução funcionava, embora não o atendesse 100% bem - o
>   que inclusive me levou a dedicar mais tempo à pergunta numa tentativa
>   de prover uma solução alternativa...

O fato dele comentar é mais um motivo para a pergunta não ser apagada, ler acima, o site não pode descarrilar em uma guerrinha de egos e sim, como é o original SO, em um fórum de conhecimento. Se a sua solução não atendeu, que fique o desafio em aberto.

Ninguém sabe tudo e não existem perguntas idiotas, essa ideia de desassociar e vergonha devem ser desvinculadas do SO. Até porque, depois de respondido tudo é fácil, o site tem que ser agradável tanto para quem responde como para quem pergunta, visto que aqui uma pergunta tem 1 ou 2 resposta e no original 5 ou 6. As pessoas não entenderam que o objetivo é agregar e não vencer. Aí cabe a moderação evitar perguntas ruins também e a nós proteger o núcleo de conhecimento, sem ofensas e deméritos por perguntas "inocentes".

Comment: Desculpe, discordo de *tudo*, mas o mais grave é **cercear o direito do AP remover o próprio conteúdo**.