# O que fazer quando um usuário remove a pergunta e reposta?

Tags: debate, perguntas, exclusão, cópias-exatas

Hoje um usuário relativamente novo postou [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51142/bloco-div-de-tamanho-proporcional), com reações mistas (uns tentando ajudar, outros votando contra e/ou reclamando da falta de esforço), e algum tempo depois ao AP a excluiu e postou [uma outra pergunta praticamente igual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51156/bloco-div-de-tamanho-proporcional-%C3%A0-ele-mesmo). Aconselhei-o a não remover e repostar, mas percebo que não temos uma diretriz "oficial" sobre o que fazer nesses casos.

O que fazer então quando uma pergunta é excluída e repostada? Isso pode ser feito, ou deve ser evitado? Se a resposta for "evitado", como a comunidade deve se comportar a respeito?

Answer (score 7):

Eu acho que se não causa maiores problemas podemos deixar. Como sempre temos que analisar caso a caso.

Mas se for generalizar eu diria que não é ideal, a pergunta deveria ser feita e se manter ali. Edição é o caminho até que a edição crie um problema (invalidar respostas dadas).

Obviamente se tem uma resposta a remoção deveria ser quase proibida ([já discutido na sua outra pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2425/o-que-fazer-quando-um-usu%C3%A1rio-remove-a-pergunta-sem-aviso)).

Claro que não posso dar uma posição oficial definitiva mas acho que devemos desincentivar esta prática, pedir para o usuário se manter na pergunta original, orientá-lo a usar a ferramenta da forma correta enquanto for possível.

Por outro lado forçar o usuário a remover a pergunta nova e ficar na antiga também não deveria ser o caso. A não ser que a troca cause algum problema. Aí não tem dúvida. Flexibilidade tem limite. E este limite é determinado pela causa de problemas.

Apenas minha opinião.

Comment: Concordo, neste caso a exclusão não trouxe maiores problemas: a pergunta está de volta sem perdas e o usuário foi orientado. Não tem por que desfazer o que já está feito, embora não tenha sido o caminho ideal.